# How to Calculate the Execution Time of Code While Compiling?

Tags: php, execution-time

I am trying to calculate the total time it will take for the code to run completely. I want to so the time in the page, so I can display a countdown timer.

**MyCode :**

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++){
        echo "".$i."<br>";
    }
?>
```

This is the above PHP code, here I want to get the time while running the script in the browser. If I can get the time of execution before compiling the full code, then I can show a timer in the page.

Comment: PHP is interpreted, not compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the start and finish time (using [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)) and then subtract:

```
<?php
$start = time();
    for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++){

         echo "".$i."<br>";
    }
$finish = time();
$took = ($finish - $start);
echo '<br/>' . $took;
?>
```

Edit: Just noticed you want to get the execution time BEFORE "compiling."   No, that's not possible. You can only get it after running the code (which means, obviously, its already been interpreted).  You can run it a bunch of times and take an average of the running times.

Comment: Yes this is correct , i can get the total execution time , but it will be better if i can get the time while running the script.